# Can I try Adobe Photoshop without buying a license?

Tags: photoshop

I want to learn Photoshop. Although no idea about it, I have downloaded some manuals,  most of them on Adobe Photoshop CS6.

No idea what that is. Started to read it and figured out first I have to install it.

Then came to know from Adobe website that I have to purchase it. But there also I have confusion.

I mean, there are options like individual or student/teacher or institution etc. Monthly payment or annual prepaid payment etc.

I also found somewhere which says that I need to have the previous Adobe Photoshop CS5 version. which I don't.

What are these? Please can you make these clear for me? What shall I do? What shall I buy?

Without buying it, can I learn ? Is it possible to get Adobe Photoshop CS6 without license ? Or any other alternative so that I can learn photoshop practically?

Comment: Why not try the free of charge program [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) first? It has a lot of the same functionalities as Photoshop, it is a bit less powerful but you won't be bothered by that at this stage. Also, if you become proficient at using GIMP but you need to do more like aligning pictures there are separate free of charge programs for that or you can download GIMP plugins.

Comment: Sir that was really a helpful information. I didn't know about it. After searching about I am satisfied now. Thank you so much once again for this valuable info

Comment: i am in trouble again. please help me by sharing the exact download link of GIMP. what i am getting again and again is gimp help 2.8   :-(

Comment: Try here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-win/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a [30 day free trial](https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/photoshop) at which point you can purchase a license or discontinue use.

That being said, you could also try [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) as suggested by [@Count Ilblis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/28357/count-iblis).

Comment: Install this gimp version if you use mac OS: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html It has some extra plug-ins and changes